# ArCore Sceneform: Need a way to ignore rendering the fragments behind an object

Tags: android, opengl, arcore, sceneform

Say I have a two parallel planes with textures and they have culling enabled on one side so that the images on the plane face each other. Now when you go outside the first plane, and look at the second plane through the first plane, I can still see the second plane texture.

I want the first plane to occlude the second one, even when the culling is enabled on one of it's side, just like how an AR portal would work. I have already tried setting a custom .mat file, trying variations with the depthWrite, colorWrite and some other parameters of it.

Comment: Maybe `renderable.setRenderPriority` will help.

Comment: @DerekK I have done that as well. setRenderPriority on one of the planes, and it doesn't seem to work as expected. You expected that just render priority and culling can do the trick? I can try that again in different ways if you are positive  about that.